Validate known_hosts base64
I would like to check all base64 encoded data in my known_hosts. I have a software that complains there is a illegal character and I can not tell in which line. There are 270 lines in my known_hosts file.
I notice there are 3 different base64 strings in most lines.
For example:
|1|SL7caYOIyaf6J+E6tMk3mRnyjBg=|3sXYrq/40lXL1XTnB1NLM9OxuBY= ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 AAAAE2VjZHNhLXNoYTItbmlzdHAyNTYAAAAIbmlzdHAyNTYAAABBBNQdXDs17bJoXeu3VnDu5btlSY3qqDPhMlixQl/J0BCTvIwY9Z/ggO+XLzWeSBBoEMEHlHZhgJ6MvtH9pBZ7wlY=

I know I can check base64 with
echo "SL7caYOIyaf6J+E6tMk3mRnyjBg=" | base64 --decode

But how can I check all 3 strings in each line?

I checked the file with those three commands:
cat ~/.ssh/known_hosts | awk -F '|' '{print $3}' | base64 --decode | grep 'invalid input'
cat ~/.ssh/known_hosts | awk -F ' ' '{print $1}' | awk -F '|' '{print $4}' | base64 --decode | grep 'invalid input'
cat ~/.ssh/known_hosts | awk -F ' ' '{print $3}' | base64 --decode | grep 'invalid input'

If they return nothing all base64 strings are correct.
I noticed some lines starting with:
domain.com ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABA..

Instead of:
|1|SL7caYOIyaf6J+E6tMk3mRnyjBg=|3sXYrq/40lXL1XTnB1NLM9OxuBY= 

After I removed all those lines everything worked.
